# How to delete a ForeignKey set?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following relationship:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ....
class Task(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
    ....
```

Now, I have a `Job` object with `Task` objects tied to it, and I want to delete all the job's tasks.

From the documentation I understood that I can just use

```
Job.objects.get(pk=25).task_set.delete()
```

But for some reason, my `task_set` object doesn't have a `delete()` function:

> *** AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'delete'

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Sayse *** AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'delete'

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maybe do `Job.objects.get(pk=25).task_set.all().delete()`

Answer (score 0):

The method is `.clear()`. See [the related objects documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear).

Comment: `clear()` just disassociates the connections, not actually deleting, is it?

Comment: + for making me know this function exists

Comment: link is giving a 404